# Are there any window managers for Gnome that can remember where my windows should be in different layouts?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, hdmi, window, window-manager

I have an Ubuntu laptop that I often have connected to a large (3440x1440) monitor via HDMI. But, being a laptop, I naturally unplug from the external monitor quite a lot. And other times I connect the laptop to other HDMI devices which are often at different resolutions than my usual external monitor, like a shared conference board for instance.

Each and every time I switch from one layout (1 display) to another (2 displays, sometimes of varying sizes), the position of my windows on screen is invariably wrong. Sometimes windows that had been pinned to 50% of the monitor are maximized, sometimes they're not, sometimes they're completely off screen, and so on. It means that every time I switch layouts there's also a mandatory period of time where I'm dragging things back to where they "should" be.

Are there any applications for Gnome/Ubuntu that can do this for me? Anything that can remember, for instance, that if I have two displays, one being 1920x1080 and the other being 3440x1440, that Chrome should be over here, Slack should be over there, the Terminal should be maximized on that display, etc. And then if I switch to just one display with 1920x1080, then these same programs should be in various other positions/sizes?

Comment: You can have a different script for each environment. The complexity is knowing the Window names that will be open. An even better script would be self learning where you tell it to rewrite itself based in current opened windows. More challenging to write a script that rewrites itself but arguably more fun too. Or you can go the grub route and make rewriting a script easier by sourcing the rewritten script subroutine

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that sounds interesting but I'm not sure where to start when it comes to scripts. Would those be bash scripts, or something else? Are there some built-in hooks that can be fired on display changes?

Comment: There are ways of monitoring when dbus changes screen layout but I was thinking of a bash script you would manually call from command line or shortcut key.

Comment: I''ve been thinking of writing a little app to do this. It would benefit me when rebooting laptop and getting windows from auto started applications placed where desired on three monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python script for this. It stores & restores window layouts for specific screen setups. One can configure the script to automatically

1. store the current window layout for the current screen setup,
2. switch to a configured screen setup using xrandr, and
3. restore a window layout previously stored for the new screen setup.

https://github.com/truhanen/windowlayouts

Comment: Can it run automatically when connecting to external monitors?

Comment: At the moment there's nothing but a Python script. You'll need some kind of service daemon for automatic invocation.